clink-clink as I pedal
Only happens with any pressure on the pedals.
In normal use it clinks twice per pedaling cycle.
More specifically, it does it any time there is any pressure on the pedals and I suddenly release that pressure.
Tried adjusting these 4 screws without success. Anything gives ?



In response to your suggestions:
The crank itself does not appear to be loose.
The clinking is present on other sprockets / chainrings
Standing up out of the saddle makes no difference
What does make a difference is back-pedaling with equal force on both pedals - the clinking almost disappears. If unequal forces when backing off on the pedals then it behaves as described above in the OP text.
More to the above, I have turned the bicycle upside down and hand pedaled backwards. I can feel and hear multiple nano-clinks. This together with the previous point makes me think it has something to do with the bottom bracket.
I shall take off the pedals too and clean / grease them; one of them won't freely move, the other does, and makes quite a sound - as off worn out bearings.
Oh, and I am unable to exert enough pressure by hand in order to reproduce the issue with the bike upside down like that.
The teeth on chainrings look fine to me.
Extra
FWIW: this bike has never done very well. I had to take it to the shop when it was brand new some 7-8 years ago for some front chain related adjustments.
This clinking has developed some months ago along with the chain going off the chainring especially on the smaller chainrings. I have since cleaned the back parts (loooots of grime there) and the situation has improved a lot. Chain won't slip anymore on largest chainring, it still does it on the smaller ones. Not sure if this is related to the clinking though. My bicycle is optimized to run on largest chainring and a few rear sprockets. Anything else it makes extra noises, at the very least.

Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Did you check if the crank itself was loose?

@DavidW yes I did. Feels stiff when pulling & rocking.

If the chain is slipping off the chainrings and it's 7-8 years old, there are good chances the chainrings are worn. Clicking can be caused by a myriad of things including worn BBs, loose bolts on pedals and loose QR-skewers.  Worn BBs can cause wobbeling causing intermittent chain-FD rub but can also make clicking sounds from their internal workings.

@WornChain I am about to order some parts from a bike shop.  How do I tell if the chainrings are worn ? they look fine to my untrained eye. The chain is about 3 years old.
Really, the quick release bolts can do that ?...

Yes, I've experienced it myself. More of a creak than a clink, but still, people might describe sounds differently, it's easy to check and critical not to miss. The tooth profile changes(can be hard to see without a new to compare with), the chain rises/slides upwards on the teeth when you start applying torque on the cranks while keeping the bike still, even if the chain is new. The same phenomenon can be seen on a worn cassette. The final stage is slipping when riding hard. If the chainrings look fine, hopefully they are. Cassettes and chains usually wear much faster.

Sure it isn't the very long front derailleur cable excess? happens all the time on new bikes. Bend it out of the way or cut it shorter. I can see how far it's overhanging so don't tell me it never touches the crank!

Forget the back end - since the noise is timed with crank rotations and is independent of which gear you're in, it is coming from the front part of the transmission.
Try getting your bike off the ground, either in a workstand or hang it up from some rope and a convenient tree branch.   Then look closely at the chain area while hand-pedalling slowly.
Be aware there's a lot of pinch-points, and it is possible to trap a finger or loose hair.    Be careful!
Try to isolate causes - Work out the crank-angle when the noise appears.  Ride the bike out of the saddle and see if that changes anything.   Pedal backward and see what that shows.   Does the noise appear when in either chainring or just one?
I'm suspicious of a bent/broken tooth in the chainring, pedals, something hitting the cranks as you pedal, BB bearings, a loose crank/BB joint, a crack in the frame, a side plate/joiner loose in the chain itself, a bent or damaged chain.
The screws you're fiddled are definitely the limit screws on the FD, and probably the same on the rear.  These are unlikely to be your problem, they limit how far over the chain can go, preventing it from dropping off the side.  This wouldn't cause the periodic noise described, instead it would be a continuous rubbing.  Try and restore them to their original position, and if the chain does fall off the inside/outside, then tweak the screws.

Hey, care to look over the edit i have made ? Thanks!

@kellogs what's the mileage on the chain?  Is it stretched?   Could be after 7-8 years its time for a transmission overhaul anyway.     I'd suggest pulling the bottom bracket for inspection, and if there's any doubt just replace it.  Cartridges are surprisingly cheap.   Basically fire the parts cannon at the bike with chain, cassette, maybe BB cartridge, maybe jockey wheels, maybe brake pads too depending on condition and hardness.

Well the chain is around  3 years old, I put no more than 400 km yearly on it.
